# Object Deletion Management in javacards

Tags: javacard

Below, You see a part of *Application Programming Notes Java Card 3 Platform Classic Edition* about object deletion management :

```
void updateBuffer(byte requiredSize)
     {
     try
       {
          if(buffer != null && buffer.length == requiredSize)
             {
              //we already have a buffer of required size
              return;
             }

          JCSystem.beginTransaction();
          byte[] oldBuffer = buffer;
          buffer = new byte[requiredSize];

          if (oldBuffer != null)
             JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion();

          JCSystem.commitTransaction();
      }

    catch(Exception e)
      {
          JCSystem.abortTransaction();
      }
   }
```

The question is :

When I call `JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion();` in the `if`expression, How it recognize which one the *buffer* or *oldBuffer* object must be delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object deletion is typically performed during start up. So basically the system can sweep the memory just like a normal Java Garbage Collector at that time.

If no references are found to a specific object, then the space occupied by that object can be collected. As the `oldBuffer` reference is *out of scope* by that time there will be no reference to the old array left. The exact memory management is implementation dependent.

Comment: Just to be sure that I got the point: did you mean : In the line `byte[] oldBuffer = buffer;` I create a variable name _oldBuffer_ refers to _Buffer_. In the next line by `buffer = new byte[requiredSize];`  I change the reference of _Buffer_, and therefore the _oldBuffer_ become a variable without any reference. so in the next line it condition of `if` is true (i.e. `oldBuffer=null`), and the ObjectDeletion deletes it. right?